# ASP.NET / Ajax - How do you pass a parameter in your call?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, sql, ajax

I am trying to filter down my results and can't figure out how to set up the ajax query to work properly with the select2 drop down. From what I can tell you are supposed to use data, but that is not passing just the value in and filtering down my call.

Here is my ajax:

```
            $('#e1').select2({
                placeholder: "Select an ingredient...",
                minimumInputLength: 2,
                ajax: {
                    url: "../api/IngredientChoices",
                    data: 'mi',
                    dataType: "json",
                    quietMillis: 500,
                    data: function (term, page) {
                        return {
                            q: term,
                            page_limit: 10,
                            page: page

                        };
                    },
                    results: function (data, page) {
                        var more = (page * 10) < data.length;
                        console.log(more);
                        console.log(data);
                        return { results: data, more: more };

                    },
                    formatResult: function (post) {
                        markup = '<strong>' + post.text + '</strong>';
                    }
                }
            });
```

Here is my controller:

```
    public List<Models.IngredientChoices> Get(string param)
    {
        var choices = (from i in _context.IngredientItems_View(param)

                       select new Models.IngredientChoices
                       {
                           id = i.ItemID,
                           text = i.ConcatName,
                       });
        return choices.ToList();
    }
```

The ajax call returns all values currently.

Comment: They do I believe, where are you seeing the issue?

Comment: what form of data does `url: "../api/IngredientChoices",` expect? the default? `'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, as @jmordyk said was that my `q:` term did not match my parameter in c#. I changed this line:

```
public List<Models.IngredientChoices> Get(string param)
```

to be:

```
public List<Models.IngredientChoices> Get(string q)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a duplicate member `data:` on your ajax - you should only have one.

EDIT: just a SWAG but perhaps you need a class:

```
class myparam {
  string q ;
  int page_limit;
  int page;
}
//decorate for JSON
public List<Models.IngredientChoices> Get(myparm param)
{
    var choices = (from i in _context.IngredientItems_View(param.q)
```

Comment: Please ignore that I put it in for testing but the code still does not work with it removed.

Comment: Either that or the parameter name in the Controller method needs to mach the name of the variable sent as the data from the AJAX function for the model binder to work.

Comment: You were right @jmoerdyk - I needed to change my param in c# to be q and it worked.